# Display data from json array in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can I display "in" inside "pricing" from the below json array in laravel.

```
  {
   "result": "success",
   "currency": {
   "id": "1",
   "code": "INR",
   "prefix": " \u20b9",
   "suffix": "INR",
   "format": "1",
   "rate": "1.00000"
    },
   "pricing": {
    "in": {
    "categories": [
    "ccTLD",
    "Geography"
   ],
  "addons": {
    "dns": true,
    "email": true,
    "idprotect": true
  },
  "group": "",
  "register": {
    "1": "704.39"
  },
  "transfer": {
    "1": "704.39"
  },
  "renew": {
    "1": "704.39"
  }
}
```

Am using whmcs api and how can display the data "in" inside array "pricing" in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a variable. Then...

```
json_decode($yourJsonVariable->pricing->in, true);
```